# Yocto: what is the best practice for having a recipe install config files for another application, but only if said application is to be installed?

Tags: config, yocto, bitbake, openembedded, yocto-recipe

What is the recommended way to include config files depending on the presence of another package or recipe in an image?

For example, if the `python3-supervisor` recipe is included in a target image, what is the best way to write a custom recipe so that, in this case, the recipe installs a `foo.conf` file into `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` directory, and if the `python3-supervisor` recipe is *not* installed, then it does not do that?

I was looking at `DISTRO_FEATURES` as that is sometimes used for installing `systemd` unit files, but there's also `IMAGE_FEATURES` which might work too if the `.conf` files are put in their own packages - e.g. `foo-conf` installs `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/foo.conf` but only if, say, `IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " supervisor-conf"`.

I wasn't able to find any recommendations in the bitbake manual on how to do this properly. Is there a good example in any of the OpenEmbedded layers?

In my case I'm writing my own recipes for my own applications, that would install their own `.conf` files into `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` if the `python3-supervisor` recipe is installed, and fall back to something else (or nothing) if it isn't, but the problem can be thought of as a more general "how do I gate the installation of certain files based on what's going into the image?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no reliable way for one package to know what other packages from other recipes are installed in a particular image (each package is built independently of the packages from other recipes, and may or may not be included in the final image), it seems a good way to do this is with a custom `DISTRO_FEATURES` string.

For example, in `local.conf` one can specify an arbitrary custom feature, let's call it `supervisord`:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " supervisord"
```

Then in individual recipes, the following can be used to selectively install `supervisord` `.conf` files, if this feature is selected:

```
# myrecipe.bb

SRC_URI = " \
          ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'supervisord', 'file://myrecipe.conf', '', d)} \
          "

# ...

do_install() {
    if ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'supervisord', 'true', 'false', d)}; then
        install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/supervisor/conf.d
        install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/myrecipe.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}/supervisor/conf.d/myrecipe.conf
    fi
}
```

Unlike `IMAGE_FEATURES`, this does not require the features to be pre-defined in a `.bbclass` or somesuch. Instead, `DISTRO_FEATURES` is just treated as space-delimited list of strings, and the check for a particular string in this list is trivial.